# What is the name and formula of this structure?

Tags: molecular-structure, structural-formula

Could anyone please let me know the formula and name of this structure? Any answer is helpful. Could you also summarize how to deduce the formula?

Here is an image:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE! Take the [tour] to get familiar with this site. Mathematical expressions and equations can be [formatted](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/4945) using $\LaTeX$ syntax.Please see our [guidelines on how to ask nomenclature questions](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/3066/).

Comment: Do some research on statins before asking for an answer to what looks like a homework assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's Atorvastatin, a cholesterol lowering drug (works by inhibiting the enzyme HMG-CoA reductase).
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atorvastatin
For more data, see e.g. https://www.trc-canada.com/product-detail/?CatNum=A791725